# How to get percentage progress from a BufferedReader?

Tags: java, android, apache-commons-httpclient

```
@Override
    protected StringBuilder doInBackground(String... url) {
        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url[0]);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    response.getEntity().getContent()));
            long content = response.getEntity().getContentLength();
//Do not need 'String line'
            String line = "";
            StringBuilder htmlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            long bytesRead = 0;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                htmlBuilder.append(line);
                bytesRead = bytesRead + line.getBytes().length + 2;
                publishProgress(new Integer[]{(int) (((double) bytesRead / (double) content) * 100)});
            }
            return htmlBuilder;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

'long content' is returning a -1. This means that the content is larger than the max value of the long class.

To try and have it return something else I tried to extend DefaultHttpClient=>

```
public class ImprovedHttpClient extends DefaultHttpClient implements HttpClient {
    @Override
public final HttpResponse execute(HttpUriRequest request)
        throws IOException, ClientProtocolException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.execute(request);
}
```

}

The above method is final so I cannot extend it and use polymorphism...I am stuck on how to get the percent progress and I do not want to use another library.

Why do I have to implement HttpClient? According to apache documentation, DefaultHttpClient already implements HttpClient; it makes no sense that I have to implement it. However, I can see how eclipse would prevent me from finding it because final methods cannot be extended.

In conclusion, How do I get the total bytes of content from the DefaultHttpClient without it returning -1?

EDIT
This is printed from

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(response.getAllHeaders()));
```

Stackoverflow successfully gives me back the percentage progress using this url: `("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306245/how-to-get-percentage-progress-from-a-bufferedreader#20306306");`

```
[Cache-Control: public, max-age=33, Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8, Expires: Sat, 30 Nov 2013 22:37:14 GMT, Last-Modified: Sat, 30 Nov 2013 22:36:14 GMT, Vary: *, X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN, Date: Sat, 30 Nov 2013 22:36:41 GMT, Content-Length: 51468, Via: HTTP/1.1 127.0.0.1:2020 (Brazil/2.0), Server: Brazil/2.0, Connection: Keep-Alive]
```

Google Returns -1:
    https://www.google.com/

```
[Date: Sat, 30 Nov 2013 22:41:44 GMT, Expires: -1, Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1, Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=4c028dc2b639abc2:FF=0:TM=1385851304:LM=1385851304:S=we-TWKR-LtJcomHN; expires=Mon, 30-Nov-2015 22:41:44 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com, Set-Cookie: NID=67=mId7x6boTt6BYcAWipXzM4Fjt_WGl7KQPgcHdPkA9yiOgHf8pTWl5k38AfFnA68NjL34rDRYsveh-QdLKcyoAzDZRigGe_5ydrwiELRSkW24Q0J7NdtErEnT93WXMjgM; expires=Sun, 01-Jun-2014 22:41:44 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly, P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info.", Server: gws, X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block, X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN, Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic, Transfer-Encoding: chunked]
```

Comment: -1 means that the content length isn't known.

Comment: No it means that the content length is over Long.MAX_VALUE, Right?

Comment: No, it means that the content length isn't known. Try googling it.

Comment: @Keppil 
"Returns:
    the number of bytes of the content, or a negative number if unknown. If the content length is known but exceeds Long.MAX_VALUE, a negative number is returned."

I think you are right.

Comment: I recommend that you check values of `response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()` and also print all headers you could get from your response. I am particularily interested in `Content-Encoding`

Comment: @kiruwka response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() has printed out 200 for every website I have tried.

Comment: @horvste Ok, how about trying header now : `Headers[] headers = response.getAllHeaders(); for (h : headers) { Log.d(TAG, h.getName() + " : " + h.getValue());` Can you show the output for the case of lengh -1 ?

Comment: @kiruwka it looks like you were right. It you see my above edit to the question, the stack-overflow link sends the header "Content-Length: 51468" where Google does not send a content length header.

Comment: @horvste Yes, and I think I know the reason why google does not show it, just a sec.

Comment: @horvste I was thinking about google redirecting you to https instead. Did you actually get 200, or 30x in case of google status code response ?

Comment: @kiruwka I am getting 200 when calling response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()

Comment: @horvste well, I guess you are out of luck. It doesn't make sense to show a progress for text/html pages though, so you could just guess (as someone answered below) the size to be 100k bytes. I imagine size content-length is crucial to know when you download binary data(images,music,etc)

Comment: @kiruwka I am doing a html parsing task where I need to download the data and save it to internal/external storage. The user needs to have some indication of when the downloading will be done since it is multiple webpages. I guess I will try to get the progress and if it doesn't work I will show a progress circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some situations where an HTTP client can not know the size of the thing you are getting.  The HTTP header has a place to declare the content length, but that is not required.  In the situation where the server does not specify the content length, the HTTPEntity returns a -1 for length.

In this situation there is no way to report download progress accurately.  You could make a "guess" at the content length.  Or if there is significant processing after download, you could download the entire thing, and then report progress on the processing.

Check to see if the server is sending the content length for the case you are testing.

Comment: Why does HTTP client not know, is it just because the header is not there? How would one go about guessing? This method does work for the url: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306245/how-to-get-percentage-progress-from-a-bufferedreader"

Comment: If the server is dynamically generating the content (such as with a PHP or JSP generated page) it may not be possible to determine ahead of time what the size of the content will be, so the content length header is omitted. In order to set the content length header correctly, the server has to have the entire content generated, before it sends the header.  In the case of a file download, this is easy because the content is just the file.  Or the server might buffer the entire response, before sending any of it.  But ... if the server generates & streams directly, it can not know in advance.

Comment: Guessing would be difficult.  It would have to be some special situation where you knew what was coming.

Comment: So in theory I could load the websites which I plan to download then hard-code the byte values and use those to guess the progress?

Comment: Well, for example, if you are reading pages from Google search, you will find that they tend to be around a certain length +/- 20%.  That is because they are truncating the content on the ten or twenty results they are displaying, and because the number of hits displayed is fixed.  This is a "special situation" where you might be able to approximate the size well enough to give a progress bar.    But it is faulty and probably not worth it.  You will notice that browsers typically have two progress indicators: one when they know the content length, and another when they don't.